# ideal of a localized ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, localization

There is a statement  which says, if $I$ is  an ideal of the localized ring $S^{-1}A$ then there exists an ideal $J$ of the ring $A$ such that $I=JS^{-1}A$. I'm failing to prove it.

When $I$ is an ideal of $S^{-1}A$ , it means for every $i\in I$ and $\frac{a}{s} \in S^{-1}A$  : $i*\frac{a}{s}\in I$

Otherwise when $J$ is an ideal of $A$, it means for every $j \in J$ and $a \in A$: $j*a\in J$.
How can I connect both ideals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varphi:A\longrightarrow S^{-1}A$ be the canonical map $a\longmapsto \frac a1$, and consider 
$$J=\varphi^{-1}(I)$$
We  of course have $\;\varphi(J)\subset I$, hence $\;\varphi(J)S^{-1}A\subset I$.

Conversely, if $\frac as\in I$, we also have, since $I$ is an ideal of $S^{-1}A$, $\frac a1\in I$, so by definition, $a\in J$, and
$$\frac as=\frac 1s\cdot \frac a1\in S^{-1}A\cdot\varphi(J).$$

Comment: Thanks, so because of $\varphi(J)=J$ I can conclude my assumption,right?

Comment: $\varphi(J)$ and $J$ can't be equal since they do not live in the same set – furthermore, $\varphi(J)$  is not an ideal of the ring of fractions. The correct way to write is with $\varphi(J)$. Of course, usually, the abuse of notation $JS^{-1}A$ is accepted.